# document.body.onload not working with CefSharp ExecuteScriptAsync

Tags: javascript, cefsharp

Trying to inject this script into CefSharp browser window. The below script works fine as expected but I want this to be executed on onload event not with onmouseup.
So the new text message will be displayed while the cefsharp browser loaded.

currently this message appears only when I click on cefsharp broswer window.

```
private void Browser_FrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Frame.IsMain)
        {
            browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(@"document.body.onmouseup = function() {
                                                
            var main = document.getElementsById('container');
            var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
            newDiv.innerHTML = 'NEW TEXT MESSAGE';
            container.appendChild(infoDiv); 
            }
        ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Browser_FrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Frame.IsMain)
    {
        browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(@"function Method() {
                                            
        var main = document.getElementsById('container');
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.innerHTML = 'NEW TEXT MESSAGE';
        container.appendChild(infoDiv); 
        }
        Method();
    ");
    }
}
```